# Symfony2 - Current User Access to Route

Tags: php, security, symfony, routes

I have `access_control` setup in the security configuration of my Symfony app so, clearly, the application can detect if the current user has access for the current request (that works just fine). What I want to be able to is have the app figure out if the current user would have access to another request (eg. a different path or method) from a `Controller` action.

What is the proper way to do this in Symfony? I can hack together going through and accessing the `FirewallContext` of the current request and looking for the proper listener with the proper `AccessMap` but this is ugly and I fear that it will break easily. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This question has gone unanswered for almost a week now so I've found a decent workaround solution in the meantime, if anyone finds this and wants to do something similar.

First of all, I pulled the functionality from `AccessListener::handle(GetResponseEvent)` out into a new class/method `Authorization::checkAccess(Request)` which takes a `Request` object instead of a `GetResponseEvent`.

Next (and the necessity of this depends on whether or not `checkAccess` differs from the way `handle` handles requests), I created a separate class to override `AccessListener` and use `Authorization::checkAccess(Request)` to do the checking (and swapped it out in the configuration by setting the `security.access_listener.class` parameter)

Next, setup a service in the configuration to construct an `Authorization` object with all of the parameters that are injected into the `AccessListener`.

Finally, in order to check a particular request, I use this slice of code in the controller:

```
$check = $this->getRequest()->duplicate();
$check->server->set('REQUEST_URI', $requestUri);
$check->setMethod('GET');
$this->get('my_access_control_service')->checkAccess($check);
```

I hope this helps someone out there...